# How to increase xaxis in d3js v4 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to learn how to code with the d3.js. I am trying to make a simple bar graph with this json file. I got stuck trying to format the xaxis in the file. I've tried looking at the [d3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#time-formats-d3-time-format) API and I am still lost. I would be very grateful for any help. 
Here is the result screenshot

[This image is for shorter xaxis points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSXm5.png)

This output looks good

[This output results when more data points in xaxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Gd3.png)

Can anyone suggest me how to increase the xaxis length based on data point coiming to xaxis

Here is my code

```css
    .bar {
      fill: #F39473;
    }

    .highlight {
      fill: orange;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="900" height="500"></svg>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        top= 20, right= 20, bottom= 50, left=  70,
        margin = 200,
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin;

    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.4),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");

            d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {

              data.forEach(function(d) {
                  d.date = (d.date);
                  d.count = +d.count;
              })

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

        g.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
         .append("text")
         .attr("y", height - 250)
         .attr("x", width - 100)
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .attr("stroke", "black")
         .text("date");
         g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
          .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("count");
        g.append("g")
         .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d){
             return  d;
         }).ticks(10))

        g.selectAll(".bar")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("class", "bar")
         .on("mouseover", onMouseOver) //Add listener for the mouseover event
         .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)   //Add listener for the mouseout event
         .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
         .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
         .transition()
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .duration(400)
         .delay(function (d, i) {
             return i * 50;
         })
         .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); });
    });

    //mouseover event handler function
    function onMouseOver(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'highlight');
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()     // adds animation
          .duration(400)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth() + 5)
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count) - 10; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count) + 10; });

        g.append("text")
         .attr('class', 'val')
         .attr('x', function() {
             return x(d.date);
         })
         .attr('y', function() {
             return y(d.count) - 15;
         })
         .text(function() {
             return [ +d.date, +d.count];  // Value of the text
         });
    }

    //mouseout event handler function
    function onMouseOut(d, i) {
        // use the text label class to remove label on mouseout
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()     // adds animation
          .duration(400)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); });

        d3.selectAll('.val')
          .remove()
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `d3.nest()` and make a rollup out of the key value you'd want to count (`d.date` in this case) and use this count value in your `width` variable.

Here's a [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xR37SupFNuoeE6ORiWMz?p=preview) I made using this method.

Comment: if i try to run the same code u have done am getting an error d3.v4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at t (d3.v4.min.js:2)   , where i have used the same file both data.json and index.html

Comment: Are they in the same folder? Are you using a local server? Because I only get that error if I'm not loading it through a local server, which you have to do in order for the json file to load

Comment: yes both file in same folder, and i run using local server only

Comment: It could be the case that you need to have a link in the `d3.json` path. Try and add http://127.0.0.1:8080/data.json or wherever you have your json data, in the `d3.json(" http://127.0.0.1:8080/data.json",` section and adjust to whatever port you have.

Comment: If i try the same for my data set from php file the length is taken as 1 , and am getting graph as single bar,   console.log(barCount.length) is 1 , but my original Json array length is 25

Comment: Did you adjust the `.key(function(d) { return d.Letter; })` to `.key(function(d) { return d.date; })` ?